# C++ how to properly use #include?

Tags: c++, header, active-directory, include

I want to include printstuff.h in my main.cpp program. I get the no such file or directory error. I don't want to have to put the whole directory with double quotations. I just want to simply put printstuff.h How do I accomplish this?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<printstuff.h>
using namespace std;

inline void swap( int *x, int *y ) {
    int *z = x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = *z;
}

int main( ) {
    /*int x = 0, y = 1;
    swap( x, y );
    cout << x << endl << y << endl;*/

    printStuff( );

    system( "pause" );

    return 0;
}
```

printstuff.h

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void printStuff( );

void printStuff( ) {
    int count[ ] = { 1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50 };
    char symb[ ] = "abcdefghijk";

    for ( int j = 1; j < 12; j++ ) {
        char c = symb[ j ];

        for ( int i = 0; i < 11; i++ ) {
            int times = count[ i ];

            while ( times != 0 ) {
                cout << c;
                times--;
            }

            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the path of the header file in your project settings

Comment: `#include "printstuff.h"`

Answer (score 2):

In the property page of your project, put the path of your 'printstuff.h' in 'Additional Include Directories'. By doing so, you can use the header file through `#include <printstuff.h>`

So, let's say, 'some.h' file path is in 'C:\ref\include', and your project path is in 'C:\Projects'.

- If you put the path of 'C:\ref\include' in 'Additional Include Directories', you can use `#include <some.h>`.
- If you don't put the path, you have to use relative path, like `#include "..\ref\include\some.h"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by telling Visual Studio that where to Search for Include Directives.

To Do this Right Click on Project from Solution Explorer and Select Properties.

In properties Edit Configuration Properties > Include Directive. Add your directory where your Header file is placed.

Check Out the snap.
[Image Showing Include Directive Customization Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoPOK.png)

Answer (score 0):

//printstuff.h

```
#ifndef ADD_H_INCLUDED
#define ADD_H_INCLUDED

void printStuff( );
#endif
```

//printstuff.cpp

```
#include<printstuff.h>

void printStuff( ) {
int count[ ] = { 1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50 };
char symb[ ] = "abcdefghijk";

for ( int j = 1; j < 12; j++ ) {
    char c = symb[ j ];

    for ( int i = 0; i < 11; i++ ) {
        int times = count[ i ];

        while ( times != 0 ) {
            cout << c;
            times--;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
}
```

//main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <printstuff.h>
using namespace std;

inline void swap( int *x, int *y ) {
int *z = x;
*x = *y;
*y = *z;
}

int main( ) {
/*int x = 0, y = 1;
swap( x, y );
cout << x << endl << y << endl;*/

printStuff( );

system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If youy just want to add your printstuff.h add your directory in include properties of your project :
right click on your project -> properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additionnal include directory

Then add your directory and just #include your header ;)